# How do I check values in a list of class in python?

Tags: python, class

Hello I define a class person as following:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        self.name = X
        self.city = Y
names = ['Bob', 'Alex', 'John']
cities = ['New York', 'London', 'Rome']
N = list()
for i in range(0,3):
    x = names[i]
    y = cities[i]
    N.append(Person(x,y))
```

I want to to check the corresponding cities of a name automatically, something like this

```
N.name['Bob'].city =
'New York'
```

Comment: Not possible with classes (in current form). If there's a one-one relation (or one-many), then consider using dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dictionary with name as key:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, city):
        self.name = name
        self.city = city
names = ['Bob', 'Alex', 'John']
cities = ['New York', 'London', 'Rome']

persons = {n: Person(n,c) for n,c in zip(names, cities)}

print(persons['Bob'].city)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use python dictionaries

```
people = {}
names = ['Bob', 'Alex', 'John']
cities = ['New York', 'London', 'Rome']
if len(names) != len(cities):
  # You might want to do something other than a base exception call here
  raise Exception('names and cities must be of equal size')
for i in range(len(names)):
  people[names[i]] = cities[i]
print(people['Bob'])

>>>'New York'
```